# If $\partial\Omega$ is of class $C^1$, does it need to be the boundary of a $C^1$-regular domain?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, submanifold

Let $d\in\mathbb N$ and $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$.

In [*Theoretical Numerical Analysis*](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9781441904577), the notion of $\partial\Omega$ being "of class $C^1$" is defined in the following way:

[image]

On the other hand, in [*Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9781441999818) (p. 120) $\Omega$ is said to be "$C^1$-regular" if $\Omega$ is a $d$-dimensional properly embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary. In that case, the manifold and topological boundary coincide and $\partial M$ is a $(d-1)$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$.

> So, I wonder how these two definitions are related. In the former, $\Omega$ is assumed to be $\mathbb R^d$-open, while in the latter, $\Omega$ being properly embedded is equivalent to $\Omega$ being $\mathbb R^d$-closed. Can we generally show that if $\partial\Omega$ is "of class $C^1$", then $\partial\Omega$ is a $(d-1)$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$? Can we even show that $\partial\Omega$ must be the boundary of a "$C^1$-regular domain"?

### **EDIT**:

Clearly, if $\Omega$ is open, then it is a $d$-dimensional embedded $C^\infty$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$. So, I've got the feeling that together with assuming that its boundary is of class $C^1$ yields that $\overline\Omega$ is a $d$-dimensional properly embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$. Can we in fact show this?

Comment: Just to be clear: My book _Introduction to Smooth Manifolds_ does not mention "$C^1$-regular domains." I only treat smooth (i.e., $C^\infty$) regular domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you quoted the definition in my book *ISM* incorrectly. I don't mention "$C^1$-regular domains" at all; instead, I only treat smooth (i.e., $C^\infty$) **regular domains**, which I define as properly embedded codimension-$0$ [smooth] *submanifolds with boundary* (not *submanifolds* as in your version).  And I don't understand what the relationship between $M$ and $\Omega$ is supposed to be in your version of the definition.

My definition of regular domains can easily be extended to domains of class $C^k$: a **$\boldsymbol{C^k}$-regular domain** in $M$ is a closed subset $D\subseteq M$ that is a codimension-$0$ topological manifold with boundary in the subspace topology, endowed with a $C^k$-structure such that the inclusion map is a $C^k$ embedding.

If $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb R^d$ is a $C^1$-regular domain by the definition 7.2.1 that you quoted, then $\overline\Omega$ is a $C^1$-regular domain by the definition I just gave. Conversely, if $D\subseteq \mathbb R^d$ is a *bounded* regular domain by my definition, then its interior is a $C^1$-regular domain by your definition. (It's a matter of taste whether one considers a "domain" to be an open subset or a closed subset.) I don't have time to write out a complete proof, but the basic ingredients are $C^k$ versions of the immersion theorem for manifolds with boundary (Theorem 4.15) and the implicit function theorem (Theorem C.40), both of which follow from a $C^k$ version of the inverse function theorem (Theorem C.34). The proof of the inverse function theorem that I give in my book can easily be adapted to the $C^k$ case, just by stopping the induction when you have proved that the inverse map is of class $C^k$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've messed some things up. I've intended to define a "$C^1$-regular" set to be a a $d$-dimensional properly embedded $C^1$-submanifold with boundary. And $M$ should be $\Omega$.

Comment: Let me ask one question: If $\Omega$ is bounded and open and $\operatorname{Bd}\Omega$ (the topological boundary) is of class $C^1$, as you say, $\overline\Omega$ is $C^1$-regular. So, we know that the manifold boundary $\partial\overline\Omega$ and topological boundary of $\overline\Omega$ coincide. But does it hold $\partial\overline\Omega=\operatorname{Bd}\Omega$? In general, it is not true that the boundary of the closure is equal to the boundary (even of an open set as $(0,1)\cup(1,2)$, for example, shows).

Comment: If you interpret "topological boundary of class $C^1$" in the sense of definition 7.2.1 above, then yes. That definition implies that every boundary point has a neighborhood that contains points of $\Omega$ and points in the complement of $\overline\Omega$. But if you only ask that the topological boundary be a $C^1$ submanifold, then no.

Comment: Since I'm new to this topic, there is a chance that I'm confusing things, but if I don't miss anything definition 7.2.1 in the question is equivalent to requiring that the topological boundary $\operatorname{Bd}\Omega$ is locally $C^1$-diffeomorphic to the interior $\operatorname{Int}\mathbb H^{d-1}=\mathbb R^{d-2}\times (0,\infty)$ (or to $\mathbb R^{d-1}$, it shouldn't matter). So, it should be equivalent to requiring that $\operatorname{Bd}$ is a $(d-1)$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$.

Comment: In any case, I'm struggling to see why in the context of tangential differential operators (such as the tangential gradient) most lecture books consider extensions to tubular neighborhoods of $\operatorname{Bd}\Omega$. Maybe you can take a look: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3783358/47771.

Comment: No, Definition 7.2.1 isn't equivalent to a statement about the boundary alone. For example, consider the case in which $\Omega$ is the open unit disk in $\mathbb R^2$ with the circle of radius $1/2$ removed. Then the topological boundary is a $C^\infty$ submanifold (the union of two circles), but $\Omega$ does not satisfy Definition 7.2.1.

Comment: You wrote: *"If $D\subseteq \mathbb R^d$ is a bounded regular domain by my definition, then its interior is a $C^1$-regular domain by your definition."* But since the interior $D^\circ$ is a manifold without boundary, its manifold boundary is the empty set. Will its topological boundary be equal to the boundary $\partial $D$ of $D$?